# Caustic details not showing in render but working in viewport

Tags: rendering, caustics

I've got a 2 planes in my scene 1 with the ocean modifier and with cast shadow caustics ticked, and another with a fractal subdivision with a receive shadow caustics. For some reason, the caustics don't show up in render but work fine in the viewport.

[image]

[image: Please don't judge the activate windows haha]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that in *Ocean* modifier your *Resolution Viewport* and *Render* have the same value.